# SQL MATCH LIKE, make the id equal to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, match, sql-like

so i have this code

```
SELECT NAME, ingredient_id
FROM ingredient_aliases
WHERE (NAME) LIKE '%WATER%'
```

it shows me all the similar names to WATER

[image]

From image above, all three are Water.

I have a lot of WATER names with NULL ingredient_id. 
Is there a way i can make their ingredient_id equal to each other?

if you need more information, just tell me.
Thank you !

Comment: It's not clear what you're after, how about sample data in your question with desired results?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.? There are different ways to do this depending on the database.

Comment: @Barmar im using mysql, is there any command like "set ingredient_id equal" in sql that i can use?

Comment: Set it equal to what? You can use `IFNULL()` to return a default value in place of null.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Row 15 doesn't have `WATER` in it. `LIKE` doesn't do language translation.

Comment: You want to `UPDATE` the `NULL` value to be `666`?

Comment: @Hart CO yes, exactly

Comment: @Hart CO and update it with all null ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the ingredient ID from the non-null rows. Then use that in an `UPDATE` assignment for all the null rows.

```
UPDATE ingredient_aliases
SET a.ingredient_id = 
     (SELECT MAX(ingredient_id) AS max_id
      FROM ingredient_aliases
      WHERE name LIKE '%WATER%'
        AND ingredient_id IS NOT NULL)
WHERE name LIKE '%WATER%' 
    AND ingredient_id IS NULL
```

Comment: so i just realized that your method would work better, because really hard-coding ID would be a real pain. 
but im getting an error on the second line

 15:19:19 Kernel error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CROSS"
  LINE 2: CROSS JOIN  AS b 

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, it was a bad edit, that line was supposed to be removed.

Comment: Tnx so much ! now it's fixed and it works perfectly ! Again, tnx !

Comment: Hey, just a quick question. Can i somehow make something like a while loop for this statement? So instead of 'Water' the code will be putting all the names with the known id and keep ingredient_aliases updating?

Comment: You probably would have to do it as a join with a table that lists all the words to match against with `LIKE`, since SQL doesn't have arrays.

Comment: oh i see, tnx so much ! you saved me)

Answer (score 0):

> You want to UPDATE the NULL value to be 666?
>
> @Hart CO yes, exactly

I think that you need something like this:

```
UPDATE ingredient_aliases
SET  ingredient_id = 666
WHERE (NAME) LIKE '%WATER%'  AND 
      ingredient_id IS NULL
```

I assume that the `ingredient_id` is the same for all the waters.

Comment: @Student If this answer worked for you, you should accept it so other people having the same issue know this worked, this is how this site works. It's also a great way to thank the author of the answer.

Comment: @Student Do you really want to hard-code the ID, instead of getting it from the database? This doesn't seem like a very general solution.